# After Sending an email in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud

I have to build an outbound integration from SFMC to another system for 'Sent Email' data. I am looking for a field on which I can key off the extraction logic.

Would like to know if I can use EventDate safely? Once an email is sent out and its recorded in the system, can any process update that 'Sent Email' record?

Comment: The timestamp in the _sent or _job system view, will not be changed after sending the mail. At most a new job will be added to the view

Answer (score 0):

From the _Sent data view you should be able to treat the data as final when you've queried it.

Referencing the data view that I assume you're using (and the standard extracts should show as well):
https://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/data_view_sent/

Would it be more appropriate to use a composite of _SubscriberKey + _JobID?

Nothing should change on the 'sent' table here that acts as a log. There later may be bounce data in the bounce data view that logs failures from that send. The JOB is unique to that send, though.